# How to make a header in react have a shadow only on scroll using tailwindcss?

Tags: reactjs, scroll, header, tailwind-css, navbar

I have a header in react that I want to have no shadow when the scrollbar position is initial (0), and on scroll, to have a shadow. Here is the code to the header with and without a shadow using tailwindCSS:

**With shadow:**

```
<header className="sticky left-0 top-0 right-0 z-20 shadow">
...
</header>
```

**Without shadow:**

```
<header className="sticky left-0 top-0 right-0 z-20">
...
</header>
```

How can I check if the scrollbar is not in its initial position to make the header take the className "shadow"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple solution to your question is to create a state to check if the screen has been scrolled, update the state with a useEffect once the screen is scrolled and then add the shadow class to the header if the screen has been scrolled. Here is how I achieved it:

```
const [top, setTop] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
  const scrollHandler = () => {
    window.scrollY > 10 ? setTop(false) : setTop(true)
  };
  window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler);
  return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler);
}, [top]);
```

Then your header class would look like this:

```
<header className={`sticky left-0 top-0 right-0 z-20 ${!top && `bg-white shadow-lg`}`}>
```